# Ruby gem persist values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am working on a gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/apipie-postman) that automatically generates Postman documentation based on your Apipie output. Right now, one of the issues I have is that every time you run the rake task to generate the collection, it will generate a new collection, instead of updating the old one.

I am trying to save the collection uid as a constant, so if it's nil I should create the collection, otherwise I should update the collection based on the uid.

Until now, I tried having either an `attr_accessor` on my class, or using `Object.const_set('key', value)`. The issue is that each time I run the rake task (that is how I have set up my logic - the developer has to run a rake task to generate the docs), the `self.attr_accessor_value` is nil, and `Object.const_defined?('key')` is also nil.

```rb
parse_apipie_file_and_create_postman_body

if Object.const_defined?('postman_uid')
  Faraday.public_send(:put, "https://api.getpostman.com/collections/#{Object.const_get('postman_uid')}", body, headers)
else
  response = Faraday.public_send(:post, 'https://api.getpostman.com/collections/', body, headers)

  if response.status == 200
    Object.const_set('postman_uid', JSON.parse(response.body)['collection']['uid'])
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you share some sample code of what you are trying to do? Without a sample code, it might be hard for someone to understand the problem that you are facing.

Comment: Yes, sure. I will update the question to contain info

Comment: There is just so much problems with this approach I don't even know where to start... This is not what constants are for! Constants are global references. Using `Object.const_set` will dynamically create a constant in a global namespace, which is rarely justifiable. Also, your code would rise an exception as `postman_uid` is incorrect constant name. What you're looking for is a memoized reader method. Wrap your rake task logic in a service object to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to save the collection uid as a constant, so if it's nil I should create the collection, otherwise I should update the collection based on the uid.

I don't think that's a good idea because what happens if several people want to generate / update the docs? Each one would've a different collection id?

I think you should either ask for the uuid in your configuration or maybe you can get it via an API endpoint.

Comment: Yes, I am getting it through an API endpoint. Initially, the call will be done, the collection will be created and I want to store then, on that machine, the uid in a constant or something. I would avoid putting it inside a .txt file or something like that.

Comment: I added some of the code to the question, maybe that will help for the overall picture

Comment: You can't because, unless you write the constant to your Ruby file, it will vanish as soon as your program exits. You should try to get it every time through an GET API endpoint.